# How to run jar from .conf?

Tags: java, linux, bash

I've got the following script to run:

```
# harvest_bug
#

start on runlevel [345]

script
    java -jar /home/admin/es09AndroidUpdater/es09AndroidUpdater.jar
end script
```

But my linux machine doesn't know anything about java. If I run `java -version`, I will get

> bash: java: command not found

I guess java is not in $PATH, because I still can run Tomcat and things like that. For example Tomcat's `setenv.sh` looks like that:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/default
export JRE_HOME=/usr/java/default/jre
PATH=$PATH:$JRE_HOME/bin
export PATH
PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export PATH
export JAVA_OPTS="-Des09.config=/home/es09/es09.properties -Xms128m -Xmx1024m -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m"
```

So how can I modify the script to run my jar? Can I do this?

```
# harvest_bug
#

start on runlevel [345]

script


  export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/default
    export JRE_HOME=/usr/java/default/jre
    PATH=$PATH:$JRE_HOME/bin
    export PATH
    PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
    export PATH
    export JAVA_OPTS="-Des09.config=/home/es09/es09.properties -Xms128m -Xmx1024m -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m"
    java -jar /home/admin/es09AndroidUpdater/es09AndroidUpdater.jar
end script
```

Is that ok? Will linux run this script? Sounds very stupid, because I'm not familiar with bash, linux and things like that.

Comment: /usr/java/default/bin/java -jar /home/admin/es09AndroidUpdater/es09AndroidUpdater.jar

Answer (score 1):

The main purpose of setting java path in $PATH or $JAVA_HOME environment variable is to define the exact path of java executable.

To run your script, use

$JRE_HOME/bin/java $JAVA_OPTS -jar /home/admin/es09AndroidUpdater/es09AndroidUpdater.jar